# Compiling code in Android Studio, Google map view always shows blank?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I have a very annoying issue with a project I am working on in Android Studio.

I have another developer working on code for me, and part of the app has a Google map view.

When this other person sends me raw code, I can open the project in Android Studio, compile it, and run it on a device and everything works fine - except the Google map is blank - grey screen, with "Google" logo in bottom corner.

If this person sends me an APK file, I can download it straight to my phone, and it works perfectly. Map shows and loads as it should.

The APK he sends is compiled from the same code, but compiled at his end.

I see several questions on SO asking about blank Google maps, with possible code solutions - but because the APK works fine, it surely cant be a code issue?

I have made sure all my Android Studio is updated to the latest versions, but any time I compile the code on my machine, it shows this blank map.

Any ideas of where to look to solve this? Is there something I need to do within my install of Android Studio to get the map loading, or is there an API I need to load or install?

This is driving me nuts, because I cant make any changes directly to the code on my machine, and need to always get the other developer to make any small changes and then compile on his machine and send me the APK!

(PS: We are in different locations, so just comparing both our installations is not an option!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because , the google maps api key is generated uniquely for only one system.You have to generate for you system and add it in google developer console.

If you are using android studio. 
Go to File >> New >> Google >> Google Map Activity

Then open google_maps_api.xml from values folder

it will automatically generate the ssh key and create a google developer console link which you can open and get the key

```
<resources>
 <!--
TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=CB:41:8F:F6:BC:E8:AD:81:A1:77:3D:9B:E2:7D:06:55:E4:49:48:EE%3Bcom.map.example

You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using this line:
CB:41:8F:F6:BC:E8:AE:CB:41:8F:F6:BC:E8:AE;com.map.example

Alternatively, follow the directions here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key

Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
string in this file.
-->
 <string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">
YOUR_KEY_HERE
 </string>
</resources>
```

Once you got the key you can use it in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" /> // Ur API key from developers console
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you are using different keystore to run the app. Ask the developer to send the keystore he used to build apk, and use that keystore and run